# Django: FileField, missing content_type

Tags: django, django-file-upload

If I read the docs correctly, then the FileField in Django does not know the content_type of the file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/

I would like to store files in a Django application, but I want to query the content_type.

Examples:

- list all objects which have a file with content_type "application/pdf"
- list all objects which have a file with content_type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

What is the most django-like way to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a model as:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    content_type = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
```

The field `myfile` is for storing files, and `content_type` is for storing the content-type of the corresponding file.

You could store the **`content_type`** type of a file by overriding the **`save()`** method of **`Foo`** model.


Django file field provides **`file.content_type`** attribute to handle the `content_type` type of the file. So change your model as:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    content_type = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.content_type = self.myfile.file.content_type
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, you could query the ORM by using `filter()` as:

```
Foo.objects.filter(content_type='application/pdf')
```

Comment: probably it's about https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.content_type when file is stored in the request.FILES 
but FieldFile or FileField does not have a .content_type method. Hence, self.myfile.file.content_type will not return anything except error.